# Unable to install grub in /dev/nvme0n1 failed

Tags: boot, grub2

In my gigabyte G5 ME laptop when i tried to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS alongside with Windows i got the error at the end of the installation

`unable to install grub in /dev/nvme0n1 failed. This is fatal error`

Comment: Post this in question above. lsblk -e 7 -o name,fstype,size,fsused,label,partlabel,mountpoint,parttype You should see nvme0n1p1 as ESP if first partition and that is where you install grub. What brand/model system. Some have extra settings to lock ESP beyond normal UEFI Secure boot. Check UEFI settings & review manual.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it on a Gigabyte BRIX by disabling `Secure Boot` and the `CSM support` option.